# Angular.JS: Can't use virtual keyboard

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I want to use a fixed virtual keyboard and update input fields within  ng-repeat but i can't work.  The input text are not updated   while some input fields outside of ng-repeat  are working perfectly.

Please help

Comment: show your code bro (c)

Comment: Your virtual keyboard may doesn't mimic real keyboard events properly.